# Locus of a point with constant distance ratio $e$ to two circles.

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Please help to obtain.. in as elegant a form as possible.. the locus of point $P$ equations if its distances to two circles:

$$ (x-h)^2 + y^2 = a^2;\;(x+h)^2 + y^2 = b^2 ;\;$$

are in a constant ratio $e,$ or

$$\dfrac{ \sqrt{(x + h)^2 + y^2} - a} { \sqrt{(x - h)^2 + y^2} - b}=e.$$

I am looking at a generalization to conic sections with $ (0,\infty)$ domains for circle radii  $(a,b)$.

When $ a=0,b=0 $ we have Apollonius Circles as loci. When  $ a > 0,b >0 $ the fixed base focal points of Apollonius Circles are expanded to bigger circles and the circles themselves become *distorted* as shown below.

Required to obtain a *parametrization of the Ovals* or equations in terms of any known functions.

The set of ***new Ovals*** shown have been obtained by contour plots. Distances are positive when normal distance from point P  is outside a circle ( and so $e$), and negative when inside.

EDIT1:

[image: New Ovals const Dist ratio to two circles]

Constants used for plot of ***new Ovals*** loci when $(2h < a+b)$ for intersecting circles:

$$\;h=1.8,\;a=3,\;b=2,\;e= (-2,-1,0,1,4).$$

*In particular* I wish to know if the case of equal distances $e=-1$ is an ellipse or if the circle centers are its foci.

Comment: Does $e = \frac{\text{length from circle 1}}{\text{length from circle 2}} \:$ or  $\: e = \frac{\text{length from circle 2}}{\text{length from circle 1}} \:$

Comment: The former. In new plot/ graph it is clearly seen for case $ e=4>1 $. There is a small error in the  plot , shall correct it later.

Comment: Adding the parameterization requirement *after* @arthur has already put in so much effort on this problem (including addressing additional requests in comments) seems inconsiderate. It would be more appropriate to accept [arthur's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3755374/409) as-is, then ask about parameterizing the ovals in a separate question.

Comment: Indeed that would be proper after his several responses. As you suggest  we go the whole hog in parameterizing etc.in a later question. Did you find it interesting?

Comment: Are you trying to work out a problem in electrostatics, by any chance?

Comment: For equipotential lines between differently charged cylinders is one possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Let the center of $C1$ be $(x1,y1)$ and radius $r1$.

The center of $C2$ is $(x2,y2)$ and radius $r2$.

Z is the locus $(x,y)$.

The distance from $Z$ to the center of $C1$ is:

$$D1 = \sqrt{(x - x1)^2 + (y-y1)^2}   \tag{1}$$

The closest point from $C1$ to $Z$ is extended from the radius.

The point on the perimeter is $P1$.

The distance from the perimeter of $C1$ to $Z$ is $L1$, from $P1$ to $Z$:

$$L1 = \left\lvert  \sqrt{(x - x1)^2 + (y-y1)^2} - r1 \right\rvert \tag{2}$$

Similarly for $C2$:

$$L2 = \left\lvert \sqrt{(x - x2)^2 + (y-y2)^2} - r2 \right\rvert \tag{3}$$

$Z$ is at a  distance ratio $e$ : $L1 = e L2$

$$\left\lvert  \sqrt{(x - x1)^2 + (y-y1)^2} - r1 \right\rvert = e \left\lvert  \sqrt{(x - x2)^2 + (y-y2)^2} - r2 \right\rvert \tag{4}$$

$(x1,y1) = (h,0)$ , $r1 = |a|$.

$(x2,y2) = (-h,0)$, $r2 = |b|$

The sign changes if $Z$ is inside the circle.

---

Let

$S1 = \sqrt{(x - x1)^2 + (y-y1)^2} \tag{5}$

$S2 = \sqrt{(x - x2)^2 + (y-y2)^2} \tag{6}$

For $Z$ outside both circles the absolute signs are both $+$.

$S1 - r1 = e(S2 - r2) \tag{7}$

$S1-e S2 = r1 - e r2 \tag{8}$

$(S1-e S2)^2 = (r1 - er2)^2 \tag{9}$

$S1^2 + e^2 S2^2 -2 e S1 S2 = (r1 - e r2)^2 \tag{10}$

$S1^2 + e^2 S2^2  - (r1 - e r2)^2 = 2 e S1 S2  \tag{11}$

$(S1^2 + e^2 S2^2  - (r1 - e r2)^2)^2 = 4 e^2 S1^2 S2^2  \tag{12}$

$(S1^2 + e^2 S2^2  - (r1 - e r2)^2)^2 - 4 e^2 S1^2 S2^2 = 0  \tag{13}$

Maxima code:

```
S1 : sqrt((x-x1)^2 + (y - y1)^2);
S2 : sqrt((x-x2)^2 + (y - y2)^2);
R : r1 - e*r2;
E1 : (S1^2 + e^2*S2^2 - R^2)^2 - 4*e^2*S1^2*S2^2;
E2 : expand(E1);
E3 : facsum(E2,y,y^2,y^3,y^4,x,x^2,x^3,x^4);
E4 : subst(b,r2,subst(a,r1,subst(0,y2,subst(-h,x2,subst(0,y1,subst(h,x1,E2))))));
E5 : facsum(E4,y,y^2,y^3,y^4,x,x^2,x^3,x^4);
tex(E5);
```

Finally with all the substitutions:

$$\left(e-1\right)^2\,\left(e+1\right)^2\,y^4+2\,\left(e-1\right)^2\,
 \left(e+1\right)^2\,x^2\,y^2+4\,\left(e-1\right)\,\left(e+1\right)\,
 \left(e^2+1\right)\,h\,x\,y^2+2\,\left(e^4\,h^2-2\,e^2\,h^2+h^2-b^2
 \,e^4+2\,a\,b\,e^3-b^2\,e^2-a^2\,e^2+2\,a\,b\,e-a^2\right)\,y^2+
 \left(e-1\right)^2\,\left(e+1\right)^2\,x^4+4\,\left(e-1\right)\,
 \left(e+1\right)\,\left(e^2+1\right)\,h\,x^3+2\,\left(3\,e^4\,h^2+2
 \,e^2\,h^2+3\,h^2-b^2\,e^4+2\,a\,b\,e^3-b^2\,e^2-a^2\,e^2+2\,a\,b\,e
 -a^2\right)\,x^2+4\,\left(e-1\right)\,\left(e+1\right)\,h\,\left(e^2
 \,h^2+h^2-b^2\,e^2+2\,a\,b\,e-a^2\right)\,x+\left(e\,h-h-b\,e+a
 \right)\,\left(e\,h-h+b\,e-a\right)\,\left(e\,h+h-b\,e+a\right)\,
 \left(e\,h+h+b\,e-a\right) = 0$$

---

Maxima can solve quartics:

```
Yall : solve(E5,y);
Y1 : part(Yall,1)^2;
Y2 : part(Yall,2)^2;
Y3 : part(Yall,3)^2;
Y4 : part(Yall,4)^2;

tex(Y1)$
tex(Y2)$
tex(Y3)$
tex(Y4)$
```

---

$$y^2={{2\,b\,e^2\,\sqrt{-4\,e^2\,h\,x+4\,h\,x+b^2\,e^2-2\,a\,b\,e+a^
 2}-2\,a\,e\,\sqrt{-4\,e^2\,h\,x+4\,h\,x+b^2\,e^2-2\,a\,b\,e+a^2}-e^4
 \,x^2+2\,e^2\,x^2-x^2-2\,e^4\,h\,x+2\,h\,x-e^4\,h^2+2\,e^2\,h^2-h^2+
 b^2\,e^4-2\,a\,b\,e^3+b^2\,e^2+a^2\,e^2-2\,a\,b\,e+a^2}\over{\left(e
 ^2-1\right)^2}}$$

---

$$y^2={{2\,b\,e^2\,\sqrt{-4\,e^2\,h\,x+4\,h\,x+b^2\,e^2-2\,a\,b\,e+a^
 2}-2\,a\,e\,\sqrt{-4\,e^2\,h\,x+4\,h\,x+b^2\,e^2-2\,a\,b\,e+a^2}-e^4
 \,x^2+2\,e^2\,x^2-x^2-2\,e^4\,h\,x+2\,h\,x-e^4\,h^2+2\,e^2\,h^2-h^2+
 b^2\,e^4-2\,a\,b\,e^3+b^2\,e^2+a^2\,e^2-2\,a\,b\,e+a^2}\over{\left(e
 ^2-1\right)^2}}$$

---

$$y^2={{-2\,b\,e^2\,\sqrt{-4\,e^2\,h\,x+4\,h\,x+b^2\,e^2-2\,a\,b\,e+a
 ^2}+2\,a\,e\,\sqrt{-4\,e^2\,h\,x+4\,h\,x+b^2\,e^2-2\,a\,b\,e+a^2}-e^
 4\,x^2+2\,e^2\,x^2-x^2-2\,e^4\,h\,x+2\,h\,x-e^4\,h^2+2\,e^2\,h^2-h^2
 +b^2\,e^4-2\,a\,b\,e^3+b^2\,e^2+a^2\,e^2-2\,a\,b\,e+a^2}\over{\left(
 e^2-1\right)^2}}$$

---

$$y^2={{-2\,b\,e^2\,\sqrt{-4\,e^2\,h\,x+4\,h\,x+b^2\,e^2-2\,a\,b\,e+a
 ^2}+2\,a\,e\,\sqrt{-4\,e^2\,h\,x+4\,h\,x+b^2\,e^2-2\,a\,b\,e+a^2}-e^
 4\,x^2+2\,e^2\,x^2-x^2-2\,e^4\,h\,x+2\,h\,x-e^4\,h^2+2\,e^2\,h^2-h^2
 +b^2\,e^4-2\,a\,b\,e^3+b^2\,e^2+a^2\,e^2-2\,a\,b\,e+a^2}\over{\left(
 e^2-1\right)^2}}$$

---

There is an $x$ under the square root?.

**Does this mean the general case is not a conic section?**

---

For $a= 0$, $b = 0$

Maxima code:

```
E6: subst(0,b,subst(0,a,E5));
tex(E6);
```

$$\left(e-1\right)^2\,\left(e+1\right)^2\,y^4+2\,\left(e-1\right)^2\,
 \left(e+1\right)^2\,x^2\,y^2+4\,\left(e-1\right)\,\left(e+1\right)\,
 \left(e^2+1\right)\,h\,x\,y^2+2\,\left(e^4\,h^2-2\,e^2\,h^2+h^2
 \right)\,y^2+\left(e-1\right)^2\,\left(e+1\right)^2\,x^4+4\,\left(e-
 1\right)\,\left(e+1\right)\,\left(e^2+1\right)\,h\,x^3+2\,\left(3\,e
 ^4\,h^2+2\,e^2\,h^2+3\,h^2\right)\,x^2+4\,\left(e-1\right)\,\left(e+
 1\right)\,h\,\left(e^2\,h^2+h^2\right)\,x+\left(e\,h-h\right)^2\,
 \left(e\,h+h\right)^2 = 0$$

---

A circle is expected for the previous equation:

Try to fit the form : ${a}^2((y -y_0)^2 + (x-x_0)^2 - r^2)^2 = 0$ to it:

Expand this expression and equate the coefficients of each $x^ny^m$:

Maxima code (all variables are solved by calculation):

```
X1 : a^2*( (y - y0)^2 + (x - x0)^2 - r^2)^2;
X2 : expand(X1);
X3 : facsum(X2,y,y^2,y^3,y^4,x,x^2,x^3,x^4);

X4 : X3 - E6;
X5 : facsum(X4,y,y^2,y^3,y^4,x,x^2,x^3,x^4);

X6 : subst(0,y0,X5);

Yx0 : solve(part(X6,3),x0);

X7 : facsum(subst(part(Yx0,1,2),x0,X6),y,y^2,y^3,y^4,x,x^2,x^3,x^4);

Yr2 : solve(part(X7,1,6),[r^2]);

X8 : subst(part(Yr2,1,2),r^2,X7);
X9 : facsum(expand(X8),y,y^2,y^3,y^4,x,x^2,x^3,x^4);

Ya2 : solve(expand(part(X9,1,1)/a^2/y^4),[a^2]);

X10 : subst(part(Ya2,1,2),a^2,expand(X9));

X11 : facsum(expand(X10),y,y^2,y^3,y^4,x,x^2,x^3,x^4);

Yx0 : ratsimp(subst(part(Ya2,1,2),a^2,Yx0));

Yr2 : ratsimp(subst(part(Ya2,1,2)^2,a^4,Yr2));

EQN : y^2 + (x - part(Yx0,1,2))^2 = part(Yr2,1,2);
```

The substitutions were:

$$y0 = 0 \tag{14}$$

$${\it x_0}=-{{\left(e^2+1\right)\,h}\over{e^2-1}}  \tag{15}$$

$$r^2={{4\,e^2\,h^2}\over{e^4-2\,e^2+1}} \tag{16}$$

$$a^2=e^4-2\,e^2+1 \tag{17}$$

The result equation is:

$$y^2+\left(x+{{\left(e^2+1\right)\,h}\over{e^2-1}}\right)^2={{4\,e^2
 \,h^2}\over{e^4-2\,e^2+1}} \tag{18}$$

Centers $(h,0)$ and $(0,0)$ and inverting $\displaystyle e \rightarrow \frac1{e} \:$ produced the standard form:

$$\boxed{ y^2+\left(x+{{he^2}\over{1-e^2}}\right)^2={{e^2\,h^2}\over{(1 - e^2)^2}}} \tag{19}$$

Maxima centers $(0,0)$  $(h,0)$ , $eL1 = L2$

```
S1 : sqrt((x-x1)^2 + (y - y1)^2);
S2 : sqrt((x-x2)^2 + (y - y2)^2);
R : e*r1 - r2;
E1 : (e^2*S1^2 + S2^2 - R^2)^2 - 4*e^2*S1^2*S2^2;
E2 : expand(E1);
E3 : facsum(E2,y,y^2,y^3,y^4,x,x^2,x^3,x^4);
E4 : subst(b,r2,subst(a,r1,subst(0,y2,subst(0,x2,subst(0,y1,subst(h,x1,E2))))));
E5 : facsum(E4,y,y^2,y^3,y^4,x,x^2,x^3,x^4);
tex(E5);


E6: subst(0,b,subst(0,a,E5));
tex(E6);

  
X1 : a^2*( (y - y0)^2 + (x - x0)^2 - r^2)^2;
X2 : expand(X1);
X3 : facsum(X2,y,y^2,y^3,y^4,x,x^2,x^3,x^4);

X4 : X3 - E6;
X5 : facsum(X4,y,y^2,y^3,y^4,x,x^2,x^3,x^4);

X6 : subst(0,y0,X5);

Yx0 : solve(part(X6,3),x0);

X7 : facsum(subst(part(Yx0,1,2),x0,X6),y,y^2,y^3,y^4,x,x^2,x^3,x^4);

Yr2 : solve(part(X7,1,6),[r^2]);

X8 : subst(part(Yr2,1,2),r^2,X7);
X9 : facsum(expand(X8),y,y^2,y^3,y^4,x,x^2,x^3,x^4);

Ya2 : solve(expand(part(X9,1,1)/a^2/y^4),[a^2]);

X10 : subst(part(Ya2,1,2),a^2,expand(X9));

X11 : facsum(expand(X10),y,y^2,y^3,y^4,x,x^2,x^3,x^4);

Yx0 : ratsimp(subst(part(Ya2,1,2),a^2,Yx0));

Yr2 : ratsimp(subst(part(Ya2,1,2)^2,a^4,Yr2));


EQN : y^2 + (x - part(Yx0,1,2))^2 = part(Yr2,1,2);

tex(%);
```

$$y^2+\left(x-{{e^2\,h}\over{e^2-1}}\right)^2={{e^2\,h^2}\over{e^4-2 \,e^2+1}} \tag{20}$$

Comment: Thanks, is it still  possible to arrive at a conic-like recognizable form after the radicals are removed by squaring?

Comment: I can add that it will be messy.

Comment: Thanks. Looking for a form comparable to the canonical.

Comment: If the solution is in terms of $x^4$ and $y^4$ I'm not sure it can be reduced.

Comment: One can make some minor refinements, but I don't see a particularly "elegant" way to write the equation. (The lack of horizontal symmetry precludes anything truly "comparable" to a conic.) ... Just to mention: Your equation $(8)$ can be written $$-s_1+es_2+k=0$$ A straightforward way to eliminate the square roots is to complete what I call the "Heronic product", which in general looks like $$(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)$$ and expands to  $$-a^4-b^4-c^4+2a^2b^2+2b^2c^2+2c^2a^2$$ As all elements are raised to even powers, any square-root elements yield regular polynomial expressions.

Comment: @Blue - thanks, I was not aware of that technique for removing square roots.

Comment: @arthur: As a "technique", I don't think it's all that well-known. I see the Heronic product a lot in my research, so I've come to appreciate how it eliminates square roots, and thus I like to pass this knowledge along. :)  [This answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2830366/409) notes the meaningfulness of the Heronic product in deriving the standard eqn for the ellipse/hyperbola. (BTW: "Heronic" recalls Heron's formula for the area of a triangle: $A^2=s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$ where $s:=(a+b+c)/2$ is the semi-perimeter. Without $s$, this is $16A^2=(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)$.)

Comment: @arthur:Finally do you get the special  case of the Apollonius circle ?

Comment: @Narasimham : No. I can't see it. I had a quick look at wikipedia but I'm not familiar with Apollonius circle.

Comment: Fixed ratio of distances to two fixed points is an Apollonius circle. If one circle is replaced by a straight line and the other circle shrinks to a point ( its center ) then the locus is a conic.

Comment: @Narasimham : thats interesting. Do you think the last equation can be reduced/factored to a circle?

Comment: @arthur: I suppose it can be simplified. Do the coefficients of $ (x^4,y^4 )$ vanish on simplification?

Comment: @Narasimham : I think the form could be ${\alpha}^2((y -y_0)^2 + (x-x_0)^2 - r^2)^2 = 0$

Comment: The circle centers are $(h,0)$ and $(-h,0)$, the equations might match the standard form if the centers were $(h,0)$ and $(0,0)$.

Comment: Centers $(h,0)$ and $(0,0)$ produced:
$$y^2+\left(x+{{h}\over{e^2-1}}\right)^2={{e^2\,h^2}\over{e^4-2\,e^2+ 1}}$$

Comment: @arthur:Thanks for your careful replies. Seeing that it is not a conic curve in general, we should take  the  algebraic curve's  equation/ parametrization further on in another linked question that I would put in shortly.

Comment: @Narasimham : thanks. I'm using maxima more often and letting it do the error prone algebra.